# How to create a series of new folders in for loop in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I have created a small script that passes a vector through a loop. In this loop I am using an if else statement to check if folder exists and if not to create the folder. However, I am getting error:

> Error in file.exists(i) : invalid 'file' argument. This has to due with file.exist().

I don't understand why this isn't ok. I checked the man using help. Seems like this should be working.

```
folders<- c("RawData", "Output", "BCV", "DEplots", "DEtables", "PathwayOuts", "VolcanoPLots")

for(i in 1:length(folders)){
   if (file.exists(i)){
      cat(paste0(i, "already exists"))
   } else {
      cat(paste0(i, "does not exists"))
      dir.create(i)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looping over an index (that is, `1:length(folders)` is just the vector 1:7, not the values of the `folders` vector itself. The easiest solution is to loop over the vector itself:

```
for (i in folders) {
```

Or, if you still want to loop over the index:

```
for (i in 1:length(folders)) {
    if (file.exists(folders[i])){
      cat(paste0(folders[i], "already exists"))
    }
    else {
      cat(paste0(folders[i], "does not exists"))
      dir.create(folders[i])
    }
}
```

A quick tip: if you are debugging a for-loop, the place to start is to add `print(i)` at the start of the loop. You would have immediately seen the problem: `i` was an integer, not the first value of the vector.

Comment: thanks! close to having it, but no cigar. Will def. take your advise on the print(i) comment!